# Select Primary Key Value Without Knowing Field Name

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have 3 tables, `images`, `icons`, and `banners`, each with a unique primary key that is also auto_incremented named `image_id`, `icon_id`, and `banner_id`, respectively.

I'm looping through the above tables and I'm wondering if there's a way I can select the `id` column without specifying it's specific name.

Something like

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY
FROM {$table}
```

Where I don't have to change my table structure or use `*` as there would be much data to return and would slow down my application.

Comment: It wouldn't be very flexible, but if you have only 3 tables, you could just have a function or a mapping array that just getPkName('images') == 'image_id' and so on.

Comment: Yes, given my current situation I could just do a `substr` to remove the `s` off the end of the tablename and concatenate a `_id` onto it. I'm just looking for something more flexible than that that can be done in one SQL statement.

Comment: As far as I know, you're going to have to do an additional query to get the name (and use PHP).  What you could consider doing is grabbing all of the primary key names the first time one is needed and caching them. Depending on your situation, it might be horrible performance, but it would keep it fairly flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a LAMP guy, but it looks to me like you want the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

A query something like :

```
SELECT     pk.table_name, column_name as 'primary_key'
FROM       information_schema.table_constraints pk 
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage C 
                                    on c.table_name = pk.table_name  and
                                       c.constraint_name = pk.constraint_name
where   constraint_type = 'primary key'
           -- and pk.table_name  LIKE '%whatever%'
```

This above query (filtered to whatever relevant set of tables you need) will give you bit a list of table names and associated Primary Keys.  What that information on hand you could query something like :

```
SELECT {$PK_ColumnName}
FROM {$table}
```

Note, you might needs a more complicated syntax and string builder if you have composite primary keys (i.e. more than one field per key).   Also, the information schema can be relatively expensive to query, so you'll either want to cache the result set up, or query it infrequently.

Answer (score 4):

Just name the id columns `id` in each table. Reserve the `whatever_id` naming for foreign keys.

Comment: This is the way *I* would name the fields, however existing queries in this application will be looking for `whatever_id` nor do I think I'll be able to convince my supervisor to restructure our tables.

Answer (score 1):

The PRIMARY key is different than the column that has the primary key on it. The primary key is both an index and a constraint that is placed on one or more columns, not a column itself. Your pseudocode query:

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY
FROM tablename
```

is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT keyname
FROM tablename
```

Which is invalid. What you really need to select is a column, not a key.

Unfortunately, there is no column alias or simple function that you can use to specify the columns that have the primary key constraint. It's most likely not available because the primary key can apply to more than one column.

To see which columns have the PRIMARY key constraint, you could use some reflection by querying the schema tables, using `SHOW COLUMNS`, etc.. Simply doing `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1` would get you all the column names in the result, if you wanted to assume the first column had the primary key constraint.

Of course, you could just do `SELECT *` anyway, when you don't know the column name.

If you don't want to make an extra query to fetch the column name to construct the query, using built-in meta data, or your own, I'd heed Marc B's answer if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the standard SQL command

```
show columns from tablename
```

It will show the PRI column

Check the [online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) for more info

Comment: I would have to use some PHP in the application to extract that field name. If I could get away with something like `SELECT (SHOW columns FROM icons WHERE Key = 'PRI') FROM $table` that would be nice, but it returns the whole row, not just the `Field`

Comment: That's correct, in PHP you will have something like : for ($j=0;$j<count($arrayCol);$j++){ if ($arrayCol[$j]["Key"] == "PRI"){
                   $PRIMARY_KEY =  $arrayCol[$j]["Field"] ;}}